# Return Message with Embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to write my return code with embed but it always gives an error. 
I'm a kinda newbie in these javascript things and I need help.

Thats my code:

```
const math = require("mathjs");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "Hesap Makinesi",
  aliases: ["hesapla", "hm"],
  description: "Hesaplama yapar (matematik)",

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const roleColor =
      message.guild.me.displayHexColor === "#000000"
        ? "#ffffff"
        : message.guild.me.displayHexColor;

    if (!args[0])
      return (embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Hesaplanamadı!")
        .setAuthor("HATA BELİRLENDİ!")
        .setThumbnail(
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Generic_error_message.png"
        )
        .addField(
          `\`\` Lütfen **geçerli** bir soru giriniz.\n
            \`➥\` **Toplama işlemi için:** " + " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Çıkarma işlemi için:** " - " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Çarpma işlemi için:** " * " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Bölme işlemi için:** " / " işaretini kullanın.
            `
        )
        .setColor(roleColor));

    let resp;

    try {
      resp = math.evaluate(args.join(" "));
    } catch (e) {
      return (embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Hesaplanamadı!")
        .setAuthor("HATA BELİRLENDİ!")
        .setThumbnail(
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Generic_error_message.png"
        )
        .addField(
          `\`\` Lütfen **geçerli** bir soru giriniz.\n
                \`➥\` **Toplama işlemi için:** " + " işaretini kullanın.\n
                \`➥\` **Çıkarma işlemi için:** " - " işaretini kullanın.\n
                \`➥\` **Çarpma işlemi için:** " * " işaretini kullanın.\n
                \`➥\` **Bölme işlemi için:** " / " işaretini kullanın.
                `
        )
        .setColor(roleColor));
    }

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Hesaplandı!")
      .setAuthor("Hesap Makinesi")
      .setThumbnail(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/tr/thumb/8/85/Apple_Hesap_makinesi_Calculator-icon.png/240px-Apple_Hesap_makinesi_Calculator-icon.png"
      )
      .addField("Soru", `\`\`\`css\n${args.join(" ")}\`\`\``)
      .addField("Cevap", `\`\`\`css\n${resp}\`\`\``)
      .setColor(roleColor);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  },
};
```

And it thats my error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization
> at Object.run (C:\Users*****\Desktop\Codding*****\commands\Eglence\calculate.js:18:35)
> at Client. (C:\Users*****\Desktop\Codding*****\index.js:74:25)
> at Client.emit (node:events:390:22)

Comment: Try defining the embed first, then check for `!args[0]` and return

Comment: i tried it but now it gives nothing to terminal and it doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

Like the error stated, the `embed` was called upon before being initialized. This is most likely a result of disorganized coding. Instead of simply cramming in an object in your `return` statement, I'd recommend that you declare the `embed` first, assign it a variable, and then `return message.channel.send(embed);`.

Ex - Original Code:

```js
if (!args[0])
    return (embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Hesaplanamadı!")
        .setAuthor("HATA BELİRLENDİ!")
        .setThumbnail(
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Generic_error_message.png"
        )
        .addField(
            `\`\` Lütfen **geçerli** bir soru giriniz.\n
            \`➥\` **Toplama işlemi için:** " + " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Çıkarma işlemi için:** " - " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Çarpma işlemi için:** " * " işaretini kullanın.\n
            \`➥\` **Bölme işlemi için:** " / " işaretini kullanın.
            `
        )
        .setColor(roleColor));
```

---

Ex - New Code:

```js
//create the embed first
let errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Hesaplanamadı!")
    .setAuthor("HATA BELİRLENDİ!")
    .setThumbnail(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Generic_error_message.png"
    )
    .addField(
        `\`\` Lütfen **geçerli** bir soru giriniz.\n
                    \`➥\` **Toplama işlemi için:** " + " işaretini kullanın.\n
                    \`➥\` **Çıkarma işlemi için:** " - " işaretini kullanın.`,
        `\`➥\` **Çarpma işlemi için:** " * " işaretini kullanın.\n
                    \`➥\` **Bölme işlemi için:** " / " işaretini kullanın.
                    `
    )
    .setColor(roleColor);

if (!args[0]) {
    //then simply call it in your if statement
    return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
}
```

**Note:** I named it `errorEmbed` since I noticed you were going to send the `embed` based on two conditions, and each time you were creating the embed again. So I figured it'd probably be better if you simply created the `errorEmbed` once rather than twice.

---

Whole Code - This only fixes your embed not sending issue, which is what you're asking for:

```js
const math = require("math.js");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "hm", //Hesap Makinesi
    aliases: ["hesapla", "hm"],
    description: "Hesaplama yapar (matematik)",

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        const roleColor =
            message.guild.me.displayHexColor === "#000000"
                ? "#ffffff"
                : message.guild.me.displayHexColor;

        let errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Hesaplanamadı!")
            .setAuthor("HATA BELİRLENDİ!")
            .setThumbnail(
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Generic_error_message.png"
            )
            .addField(
                `\`\` Lütfen **geçerli** bir soru giriniz.\n
                    \`➥\` **Toplama işlemi için:** " + " işaretini kullanın.\n
                    \`➥\` **Çıkarma işlemi için:** " - " işaretini kullanın.`,
                `\`➥\` **Çarpma işlemi için:** " * " işaretini kullanın.\n
                    \`➥\` **Bölme işlemi için:** " / " işaretini kullanın.
                    `
            )
            .setColor(roleColor);

        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
        }

        let resp;

        try {
            resp = math.evaluate(args.join(" "));
        } catch (e) {
            return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
        }

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Hesaplandı!")
            .setAuthor("Hesap Makinesi")
            .setThumbnail(
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/tr/thumb/8/85/Apple_Hesap_makinesi_Calculator-icon.png/240px-Apple_Hesap_makinesi_Calculator-icon.png"
            )
            .addField("Soru", `\`\`\`css\n${args.join(" ")}\`\`\``)
            .addField("Cevap", `\`\`\`css\n${resp}\`\`\``)
            .setColor(roleColor);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```